# libssh slow for file operations download and upload

Tags: c++, sftp, scp, libssh

I followed the documentation here https://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_sftp.html
to write a small program in c to download a remote file, the program is working but downloading a 120MB file takes 12-14 seconds to complete, compared to winscp, filezilla or pscp which only takes 2 seconds to complete.
How to improve this speed?

```
PS D:\MyDartProjects\fsbackup\libssh_binding\libssh_c_wrapper\x64\Release> Measure-Command {pscp -pw Ins257257 isaque.neves@192.168.133.13:/home/isaque.neves/go1.11.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz ./go1.11.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz }

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 2
Milliseconds      : 575
Ticks             : 25755922
TotalDays         : 2,98100949074074E-05
TotalHours        : 0,000715442277777778
TotalMinutes      : 0,0429265366666667
TotalSeconds      : 2,5755922
TotalMilliseconds : 2575,5922


PS D:\MyDartProjects\fsbackup\libssh_binding\libssh_c_wrapper\x64\Release> Measure-Command {./libssh_wrapper.exe}

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 14
Milliseconds      : 360
Ticks             : 143600026
TotalDays         : 0,000166203733796296
TotalHours        : 0,00398888961111111
TotalMinutes      : 0,239333376666667
TotalSeconds      : 14,3600026
TotalMilliseconds : 14360,0026
```

```c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string.h>
#include <exception>
#include <fstream>
#include <libssh/callbacks.h>
#include <libssh/libssh.h>
#include <libssh/sftp.h>
#include "custom_exception.cpp"
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <chrono>

using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::chrono::duration;
using std::chrono::milliseconds;

//using namespace std;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;


// Good chunk size
#define MAX_XFER_BUF_SIZE 16384
int sftpDownloadFileTo(ssh_session session, const char* fullRemotePath, const char* fullLocalPath)
{
     
    int access_type;
    sftp_file file;
    char buffer[MAX_XFER_BUF_SIZE * 8];//128KB
    ssize_t nbytes, nwritten, rc;
    int fd;
    access_type = O_RDONLY;

     sftp_session sftp = sftp_new(session);
    if (sftp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating SFTP session: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(session));
        return SSH_ERROR;
    }
    rc = sftp_init(sftp);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error initializing SFTP session: %d.\n",
            sftp_get_error(sftp));
        sftp_free(sftp);
        return rc;
    }
        

    file = sftp_open(sftp, fullRemotePath, access_type, 0);

    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file for reading: %s\n", ssh_get_error(session));
        return SSH_ERROR;
    }

    fd = open(fullLocalPath, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0777);
    if (fd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file for writing: %s\n",
            strerror(errno));
        return SSH_ERROR;
    }

    for (;;) {
        nbytes = sftp_read(file, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (nbytes == 0) {
            break; // EOF
        }
        else if (nbytes < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while reading file: %s\n",
                ssh_get_error(session));
            sftp_close(file);
            return SSH_ERROR;
        }
        nwritten = write(fd, buffer, nbytes);
        if (nwritten != nbytes) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error writing: %s\n",
                strerror(errno));
            sftp_close(file);
            return SSH_ERROR;
        }
    }
    rc = sftp_close(file);
    if (rc != SSH_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't close the read file: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(session));
        return rc;
    }

    sftp_free(sftp);
    return SSH_OK;
}

int main()
{

    ssh_session my_ssh_session;
    int rc;
    int port = 22;
    string password = "Ins257257";
    auto host = "192.168.133.13";
    auto username = "isaque.neves";

    int verbosity = SSH_LOG_PROTOCOL;
    // Abra a sessão e defina as opções
    my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
    if (my_ssh_session == NULL)
        exit(-1);
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, host);
    //ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &verbosity);
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);
    // Conecte-se ao servidor
    rc = ssh_connect(my_ssh_session);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)
    {
        
        fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting to host: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session));
        exit(-1);
        
    }
    // Autenticar-se

    rc = ssh_userauth_password(my_ssh_session, username, password.c_str());
    if (rc != SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error authenticating with password: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session));
        ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
        ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
        exit(-1);
    }

    clock_t tic = clock();
    auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    sftpDownloadFileTo(my_ssh_session, "/home/isaque.neves/go1.11.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz", "D:/MyDartProjects/fsbackup/libssh_binding/go1.11.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz");
    auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    clock_t toc = clock();
    
    duration<double, std::milli> ms_double = t2 - t1;   
    std::cout << ms_double.count() << " ms\r\n";

    printf("Elapsed: %f seconds\n", (double)(toc - tic) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
    ssh_free(my_ssh_session);

    std::cout << "End\n";

    return 0;
}
```

https://github.com/insinfo/fsbackup/tree/main/libssh_binding/libssh_c_wrapper

Comment: FWIW `Measure-command` is not accurate for anything not powershell.

Comment: Regardless of the accuracy the difference is too big to easily perceive I measured the difference in several ways